# link attribute is missing from questions in /tags/{tags}/faq

Tags: bug, status-completed

Check the following requests, the `link` attribute is missing from questions objects in responses. I checked with the default filter and also with custom filters (both safe and unsafe).

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags/php/faq?site=stackoverflow
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags/php/faq?site=stackoverflow&filter=!.bzEk)B2
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags/php/faq?site=stackoverflow&filter=DLsN_e.SW

Answer (score 1):

A fix for this has been deployed.

There were actually a number of properties not being set on that method, but `link` was the most noticeable.